# Java: Ignoring CertificateParsingException

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I know this kind of questions were asked a lot, but I tried many solutions without help...

I get the following exception information:

> java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: X.509 Certificate is
>   incomplete: SubjectAlternativeName extension MUST be marked critical
>   when subject field is empty

This error was brought to the service provider attention and he works now on a solution.

But I need a workaround ASAP.

So far I have tried multiple solutions, for example:

```
private static SSLContext createSSLContext() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        context.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new HttpClientError(e.toString());
    }
}
```

But it didn't help and I am really not sure it is relevant.
But this is one of the solutions to ignore SSL issues.

Let me stress out that my code is for automation tests, so it will not affect production. At least not for now.

How can I ignore this error temporarily and continue my process?

Thanks!

Comment: > How can I ignore this error temporarily and continue my process?
You probably can't and shouldn't. I'd recommend you get rid of your `TrustManager` and `Hostnameverifier` implementations as they are highly insecure. However, these should arguably not perform any validation on a faulty certificate contextually to server authentication, so perhaps the problem occurs somewhere else in your code base? Try debugging and see if your stack trace leading to the `CertificateParsingException` really stems from the usage of your `SSLContext` as is.

Comment: You shouldn't. Period. If the communication between you and your service provider is under https, and for some reason the SSL process is failing, fix it. If it is not under your control, then I would stub the provider's response to unless not block your self.